# How can I adjust the position of images in PyQt5's QStackedLayout?

Tags: pyqt5

Hi I am trying to show 2 different image partially stacked.
but I do not know how to adjsut position of each image.
currently  both image are shown on the same position, and one was completely covered by the other.
if somebody know how to fix, let me know.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QCheckBox,QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout,
    QAction, QApplication,QLabel,QWidget,QPushButton,QRadioButton,QStackedLayout)  
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        #overall layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")        
        
        #card_area = self.card_area_blank_view()
        card_area_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        card_layout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        card_area_layout.addLayout(card_layout1)        
        layout.addLayout(card_area_layout)        
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, 330, 200)  
       
        card_w1 = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        card_w1.setPixmap(QPixmap("card/C2.bmp"))
        card_w2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        card_w2.setPixmap(QPixmap("card/C1.bmp"))
        
        stackedLayout = QStackedLayout()
        stackedLayout.addWidget(card_w1)
        stackedLayout.addWidget(card_w2)
        card_layout1.addLayout(stackedLayout)
                
        #overall layout        
        self.container = QWidget()
        self.container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)       
        self.show()
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Main()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this photo is my expectaion:

[image]

Comment: That is not the purpose of layout managers (stacked or not). If you want to provide widget overlays that are intended to provide specific graphical positions, you should consider other alternatives, like custom widgets or, probably, through the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).